# Date string dose not get parse

Tags: android, string, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have a string in date format which I want to parse in date object. I want to set the time as string in calendar object and want to set an alert at the same time.

For this I tried to parse the string into date but nothing happens. The time dose not get set.

When I did debug to check if the time get's set in calendar or not, then found that it goes directly at the end of method after the parsing.

`Date date = df.parse(alertDateTest);`

I tried to parse the string with this format :
  `SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");`

But it gives invalid format exception. Which format should I use to parse this string?

String format is : `d MMM yyyy`

code:

mAlertDate is 25 Apr 2016 
alertDateTest is 25 Apr 2016

```
 public void updateNotification() {

        try {


            String alertDateTest = i.getStringExtra("taskAlertDate");
            String alertTimeTest = i.getStringExtra("taskAlertTime");

            SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            Date date = df.parse(alertDateTest);


            if (alertDateTest.equals(mAlertDate)) {


                String formattedString = date.toString();
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHourOfTheDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                mYear = new DateTime(formattedString).getYear();
                mMonth = new DateTime(formattedString).getMonthOfYear();
                mDayOfMonth = new DateTime(formattedString).getDayOfMonth();

                c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDayOfMonth);

                date = c.getTime();

                Log.d("AlertDate", String.valueOf(date));
                Toast.makeText(AddTaskActivity.this, String.valueOf(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                intent = new Intent(AddTaskActivity.this, NotificationReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), _mId, intent, 0);
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTime(), pendingIntent);


        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I have a function onDateSet of date picker in this I have a string format and the string is formatted to the same format:

```
 @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     //   String date = "You picked the following date: "+dayOfMonth+"/"+(++monthOfYear)+"/"+year;

        SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        mCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        Date date = mCalendar.getTime();



       if(DATE_PICKER_TAG == 1)
        {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;

            mAlertDate  = df.format(date);
            alertDate.setText(String.valueOf(mAlertDate));
        }
       if(DATE_PICKER_TAG == 3) {

            mDueDate  = df.format(date);
            dueDate.setText(String.valueOf(mDueDate));
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Tried by your answer Umesh Saraswat

```
            String alertDateTest = i.getStringExtra("taskAlertDate");
            String alertTimeTest = i.getStringExtra("taskAlertTime");

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

            Date  date = simpleDateFormate.parse(alertDateTest);

          //  Date date = df.parse(alertDateTest);


            if (alertDateTest.equals(mAlertDate)) {


                String formattedString = date.toString();
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHourOfTheDay);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

                c.setTime(date);



                c.set(Calendar.YEAR, mYear);
                c.set(Calendar.MONTH, mMonth);
                c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDayOfMonth);

                date = c.getTime();
```

The date i got is wed dec 31. String was 26 april 2016. Time did not get set.

Thank you..

Comment: for `25 Apr 2016` use `dd MMM yyyy` format.

Comment: `d MMM yyyy` suppose to be like this `dd MMM yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

To parse Date String with `25 Apr 2016` use `dd MMM yyyy` string format.

For more information visit, [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: its giving an exception.  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Mon Apr 25 00:00:00 EDT 2016"
04-25 18:49:33.123 3135-3135/com.example.siddhi.googletaskmanager E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)  @Dhaval Patel

Comment: So your date string is "Mon Apr 25 00:00:00 EDT 2016" not "25 Apr 2016".

Comment: Try "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Comment: tried this too.. nothing happens. Cannot see the toast.. Please check edited question. @Dhaval Patel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "dd MMM yyyy"  or "d MMM yyyy"

Comment: I tried using "dd MMM yyyy" this for string in onDateset method as well in updateNotification method. But it gives exception. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Tue Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2016" is malformed at "ue Apr 26 00:00:00 EDT 2016"  @PankajVashishta

Answer (score 1):

as I have understood your question,

> have a string in date format which I want to parse in date object. 
>   For this first tou need to parse the String date into date formate

```
SimpleDateFormate simpleDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormate("dd MMM yyyy");
Date  date = simpleDateFormate.parse("Your date");
```

> I want to set the time as string in calendar object and want to set an
>   alert at the same time.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date)
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, mHourOfTheDay);
 c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
 c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

;

If you want to use Calendar object date into a String formate then

```
SimpleDateFormate simpleDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormate("Your Date format String");

String date  = simpleDateFormat.format(c.getTime);
```

Comment: tried your way but time did not get set please check edited question.@Umesh Saraswat

Answer (score 0):

Just added Locale to the format and it worked..

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);

Thank you all..